# Can open source product have paid components?

Tags: open-source, components, licensing

I'm in the thought process of making my application open source. Before considering the licensing options, I would like to consider the below scenario and get your opinions.

My app is using some paid components for a module to work. That is, I'm paying for a developer license and a server license for the development and deployment of that module. Is this a showstopper in making my app as an open source application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the application you make would still be Open Source, because this is your own code so you can choose what you wanna do with it. 
The way I look at it is, when you design an Open Source application that is running on Windows, it is Open Source even though it uses some code from Microsoft that is not Open Source. 
[And you can also have an application that is Open Source, but that you charge money for.](http://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source) 
If someone is experts on this field then please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: That's good to know. This means that, I can say that the app is open source. Whoever going to use, will have to pay the license fees for that particular component.

Comment: Yes. You can read more about it here [link](http://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source) 
Here they explains it really well :)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It is a good article. Though it doesn't explain my particular scenario, it conveys the fact that as far the license allows the source code to get changed, it can be called as Open Source. It's all good from this link's (http://opensource.org/docs/osd) perspective too. Will go ahead and mark this as answer.

Comment: Great, hope this resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this app to understand open source license terms (they have proprietary license too): https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/

Hope it helps.